# Is this Ranger/Cleric/Fighter/Rune Scribe build balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, multi-classing, character-advancement, runepriest

So I have a friend who is planning on building a Dwarf who will start as a ranger and level up to level 3 in that class then switch over to multiclass into a cleric for only 2 two levels, after that he told me he is going to switch over to fighter next but only have that fighter class at level 1, and here is where it gets strange to me. He said after he has multiclassed into the fighter he will then switch over to Rune Scribe. So I looked up Rune Scribe to see if it was real and apparently Its' almost like the runepriest but its in playtest mode or something like that, sorta like the mystic. So he will be a Ranger lvl-3/Cleric lvl-2/Fighter lvl-1/Rune Scribe lvl-1.

He asked me "If this is a balanced build?" I told him I have no clue. I don't even know what his play style is would be with this class. I'm guessing he is melee spell caster I guess. But I told him I'll poke around to help him out. What do you guys think

Comment: [Rune Scribe](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Rune_Magic_Prestige_Class.pdf).

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Comment: (Aside, if a comment-writer wishes to suggest that a question is better suited to a discussion forum, it's appreciated to direct askers to [our canonical list of RPG discussion forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of suggesting one or two personal favourites, so that the asker can pick the one that best suits their needs.)

Comment: I daresay I'd need a lot more info to answer this coherently. How experienced are each of you with DND and RPGs generally? How much does roleplaying and having a logical character arc matter in your campaign vs. combat tactics? And is it more important to you to get insight from technical experts on the build, or a script for asking him why he thinks he needs this peculiar combo?

Answer (score 2):

### No, this build is quite weak

Assuming the standard ability scores, on level 8 all the non-multiclass party members can have a 20, this build will have only 16. With weapon attacks this means a 20-40 percent lag on DPR per attack, and half the number of attacks reasonably expected on that level from a weapon user. If it tries to use spells the difference is even bigger, it has only 3 caster levels (2 cleric, one from ranger).

Another question is MAD, multiple ability dependency. The Ranger needs Dex 13 and Wis 13, Rune Scribe needs additionaly Int 13, and as it has no proficiency in Con saving throws, a 12 should be at least in Constitution.

As **Ranger** provides a Fighting Style, and access to 2nd level spells on level 5, a better way would be leaving out the Cleric and Fighter levels completely. The DPR would double because of Extra Attack, and would only lose a secondary fighting style, the Second Wind, and the domain.

Another good option is 6 levels of **Eldritch Knight**, same Extra Attack, a much better Second Wind, and 2 ASIs.

If more spendable spell slots are needed, 6 levels of **Valor Bard** is also quite good.

**Bladesingers** are great too, and they do not need Wis, reducing the ability dependency.

TL;DR Extra Attack is the best source of DPR, ASI is the second. He will miss out on both if he spreads himself too thin.

Answer (score 0):

Balanced builds aren't always the way to go in D&D (IMHO).  D&D is a team sport and the weaknesses of one PC are made up for my the strengths of another PC.  That said, I generally don't allow multi-classing unless the player can give me a valid role-playing reason.  For instance, why would a ranger decide to pursue theology?  Why would he (the character) give up after only 2 levels and take up the non-theological pursuit of being a fighter? Why would he (the character) go in a completely different direction and take up Rune Scribe?

Is the player willing to give up the bonuses for the increased levels in Ranger or in Cleric (obviously, but why?)?  How much RPG (non-electronic) experience does the player have? He may not realize how complicated life is going to be for him if he's fairly new.  I've had players who insist on "optimizing" their character and want to do this or that (one Warlock wanted to dip a level in Rogue only so that he could get the +2 to Perception).  My experience is that a player who wants to do something like this has a tendency to try to dominate the table.  My advice: proceed with caution.  If the player, while in character, can explain what happened to him that made him suddenly decide to quit wandering around in the wilderness and become a priest and then suddenly give up his "collar" to start poking holes in creatures with his long sword, I'd let him.  If the best answer he can come up with is something along the lines of "I think it'll be cool", make him roll a very high DC to see if the deity will accept him as a priest.